# Why was NpgsqlException.ConstraintName property removed?

Tags: npgsql

I am wondering why the .ConstraintName property on NpgsqlException was removed. I noticed it no longer existed after upgrading to npgsql 3.1.8. (I had not upgraded npgsql in a long time)

I found .ConstraintName to be very helpful, because I had quite a bit of my code dependant upon the constraint name (e.g. I was using .ConstraintName to generate "non technical" error messages to the user.)

Does this mean I need to manually parse out the constraint name each time from NpgsqlException.Message or NpgsqlException.BaseMessage or is there another way to get the ConstraintName from that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConstraintName wasn't removed. In Npgsql 3.1, errors raised by PostgreSQL are thrown as `PostgresException`, while client-side errors (e.g. networking) are thrown as `NpgsqlException` (which is also the superclass for `PostgresException`). If you catch `PostgresException` instead of `NpgsqlException` you'll find all the error properties such as ConstraintName.

This is documented in the [migration notes](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/migration.html).

Comment: oh cool! thank you very much for the info. I think I was about 12-16 releases behind, so it would have taken me a long time to find this.